# ASP MVC 4 default action for each controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, http-status-code-404

I would like to redirect users to default action for each controller.

Let's say I have: *Controller1*, *Controller2*,...
Each have a few valid actions: *Action1*, *Action2*,....
So valid URLs look like these:

***domain/controller1/***

***domain/controller1/action1/***

***domain/controller1/action2/***

***domain/controller2/action1/***

and so on.

Right now, if I type: ***domain/controller1/{any string}*** I get 404 error.
I want to redirect users to ***domain/controller1/action1*** whenever they type ***domain/controller1/{any string}*** or even ***domain/controller1/{string1}/{string2}***....
and keep 404 error for other cases (when controller does not match).

Answer (score 2):

I believe under your route config file, you add a new route like so.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "controller1/{action}/",
        defaults: new {  action = "Index" }
    );
```

Sorry if the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Map route you are looking at is a little bit tricky. If we take the simple map route "domain/controller1/{any string}" this could easily map to any url including the valid actions (anystring could be action2 right?) . So in order for the mapping to pick the right action you would have to create a specific map route for each valid action and add a generic map route that would redirect all the other urls to "action1" like code below.

```
            routes.MapRoute(name: "map1", url: "controller1/action1", defaults: new
            {
                action = "action1",
                controller = "controller1"
            });

            routes.MapRoute(name: "map2", url: "controller1/action2", defaults: new
            {
                action = "action2",
                controller = "controller1"
            });

            routes.MapRoute(name: "map3", url: "controller1/{anystring}", defaults: new
            {
                action = "action1",
                controller = "controller1",
                anystring = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

This is the best way I can think of ...